# Where is the code responsible for Luma's theme header resizing?

Tags: layout, theme, luma-theme

I have extended Luma's theme and now making changes to it. I have set min-width for my design (for certain reasons). Thing is, when you're resizing browser, header becomes all messed up cause probably some javascript code is run that resizes things (and hides account links etc.). Where can I find the code that would stop header resizing? Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
Check path in directory 
/var/www/html/website.com/app/design/frontend/Magento/themename/Magento_Theme/web/js

You will see here header phtml and css/js files.
```